# Dynamically creating image tag to show when silverlight is not installed

Tags: javascript

I'm using Silverlight.CreateObject to create a silverlight object dynamically. when silverilght is not installed it shows its own patent image from microsoft. I want to replace this image with mine...how can I do this??

Answer (score 1):

[Determine if Silverlight is installed](http://blogs.msdn.com/piotrp/archive/2008/05/07/determining-if-silverlight-is-installed-using-javascript.aspx), and then do whatever you want based on the result...

(you can find the contents of isSilverLightInstalled() at the linked site above)

```
function isSilverLightIntstalled() {
  // see website
}

if (!isSilverLightInstalled()) {
  var myImage = new Image;
  myImage.src = “image URL goes here”;
  document.appendChild(myImage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying buddy...m new to silverlight...can u plz tell me how to detect whether silverlight is installed or not using javascript...in short what to write inside isSilverLightInstalled() function ?? :-)

Comment: Click the link, and all will be revealed. It's MSDN, so I'm not self-promoting, in fact, I feel a little uneasy about simply lifting their content here.